# GitHub GraphQL Query - Count PR reviews by user for a given month

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am attempting to use GitHub's GraphQL interface to query for the number of PR's reviewed within a GitHub repo during a specific month.

Ideally, I would like to only pull comments and reviews that took place within a specific time frame.  Ultimately, I would like to group my results on a user by user basis.

```
userA  10 reviews during month
userB  6 reviews during month
userC  4 reviews during month
```

Here is the query that I have created so far.

```
{
  repository(owner: "DSpace", name: "DSpace") {
    pullRequests(last: 50) {
      nodes {
        state
        resourcePath
        comments (last: 100) {
          nodes {
            author {
              login
            }
          }
        }
        reviews(last: 100) {
          nodes {
            state
            author {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

I suspect that I will need to iterate over all pull requests and then filter reviews/comments that fall within a specific date range.

When I look at the GitHub GraphDB schema, the "reviews" and "comments" objects do not seem to be filterable by date.  I see that the available filters are first, last, author, and state.  Is there some way to express such a filter in the GraphDB query language?

I see that GraphQL provides a way to filter by boolean properties with @include and @skip.  Is there a way to pass expressions to these constructs?

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [Github GraphQL's search](https://developer.github.com/v4/query/#search) (more of a v3 REST contruct, but still available in v4 graphQL).  The [`query`](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#parameters-3) string specifies the owner, repo name, [date range](https://help.github.com/articles/understanding-the-search-syntax/#query-for-dates) of the pull requests last updated (which serves as an approximation of when comments/reviews are created), and type `pr`.

The new query, building on top of what you have so far, with a bit of modification:

```
{
  search(first: 100, query: "repo:DSpace/DSpace updated:2018-11-01..2018-12-01 type:pr", type: ISSUE) {
    nodes {
      ... on PullRequest {
        # use part of your original query from here onward
        state
        resourcePath
        comments(last: 100) {
          nodes {
            author {
              login
            }
          }
        }
        reviews(last: 100) {
          nodes {
            author {
              login
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```